# How to use strtok to parse string from TCP server

Tags: c, strtok

I am using the following program to listen to server and the use "\r" delimiter.

When I run the following program, it doesn't output anything.

How can I parse string by removing delimiter in socket communication?

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> // inet_addr()
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h> // bzero()
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h> // read(), write(), close()
#define MAX 80
#define PORT 8080
#define SA struct sockaddr
void func(int sockfd)
{
    
    char buff[MAX];
    int n;
    char str[MAX];
    for (;;) {
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));
        printf("Enter the string : ");
        n = 0;
        while ((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n') 
            ;
        write(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));            
        bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));

        read(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff));
        strcpy(str,buff);

        char delim[]="\r";
        char *str = strtok(str,delim);
        while(str != NULL)
        {
            printf("from my prog = %s \n",str);
            str = strtok(NULL,delim);
        }
        if ((strncmp(buff, "exit", 4)) == 0) {
            printf("Client Exit...\n");
            break;                                 
        }
    }
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8czd.png]

Comment: You don't want to write `sizeof(buff)` bytes, you want to write the `n` bytes you actually read. You are obviously using a very old guide, `bzero(buff, sizeof(buff));` is most often `memset (buff, 0, sizeof buff);` -- both work, but bzero is dated. See [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) for updated network programming approaches. (and there is actually a bit of folksy comedy in his tutorial to keep it from getting dry...)

Comment: All borked anyway, (the usual three reasons).